# Clean solution does not clean FakesAssemblies?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-fakes, shim

I'm trying to understand the behavior of building fake assemblies. I'm able to add Fake Assembly in my unit test project, and it compiles into the FakesAssemblies folder locally.

However, I've been having issues lately where my dll's in FakesAssemblies-folder tries to reference an older version of the "QualityTools.Fakes"-reference. This happened after I've installed Update 5 (went from Update 3) of VS2013.

When cleaning the entire solution, the FakesAssemblies seems to be still there and not recompile.

The obvious workaround for this is to delete everything in the FakesAssemblies-folder whenever I need, but is this how it's meant to work?

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom code to .csproj file (before the closing `</Project>` tag) to do it automatically:

```
<Target Name="AfterClean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(ProjectDir)\FakesAssemblies" ContinueOnError="true" />
</Target>
```

Comment: this is an excellent solution!  Previously we'd been using commands.json and Command Task Runner to execute a PowerShell script to delete FakesAssemblies, but this is much cleaner and faster!